# Custom tag support in markdown in VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, markdown

I was exploring a way to support preview of custom tags in VSCode. I have a custom tag of kind

```
> [!NOTE]
> 
> This is the first line of a note. 
> This is the second line of a note.
```

This is translated to something

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="adm-hidden">
<symbol id="adm-info">
<svg enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m20.5 11.8c0 4.5-3.7 8.2-8.2 8.2s-8.2-3.7-8.2-8.2 3.7-8.2 8.2-8.2 8.2 3.7 8.2 8.2zm-6.7 4c-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2-.3v-4.5c0-.1.1-.2.2-.4s.2-.3.2-.3 0-.1-.1-.1c-.1-.1-.5-.2-1.2-.4-.7-.1-1.2-.2-1.5-.2-.5 0-.7 0-.7.1s.1.3.2.6v4.7c0 .3-.1.5-.2.6-.2.2-.2.3-.2.3.1.1.5.3 1.2.4.6.1 1.2.2 1.6.2h.3c.4-.1.5-.2.5-.5.1 0 .1-.1-.1-.2zm-.9-8.6c-.7-.1-1.2-.2-1.5-.2-.2 0-.5.2-.7.4s-.3.4-.3.6c0 .1 0 .1.1.2s.6.2 1.5.4c1 .3 1.5.4 1.6.3.1 0 .2-.2.3-.5s.2-.5.2-.6v-.1c-.1-.1-.5-.3-1.2-.5z" fill="currentColor"/></svg>
</symbol></svg>
<div class="adm-block adm-info ">
<div class="adm-heading">
<svg class="adm-icon">
<use xlink:href="#adm-info"/></svg><span></span>
</div>
<div class="adm-body">
<p>This is the first line of a note.
This is the second line of a note.</p>
</div></div>
```

I explored showdownjs and markdown-it but both of them relied on regex. Another way was to parse the md file line by line and convert it to relevant tag.

Is there any inputs or links which could help me in achieving this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this using a [markdown extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/api-markdown#_adding-support-for-new-syntax-with-markdownit-plugins)

Specifically, VS Code allows extensions to contribute a [markdown-it plugin](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it). These plugins can add support for new markdown tags